# nil can't be converted to a Time value

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im building a basic chat room website with multiple chat rooms that users can comment on.

I managed to get my messages/comments to show up on each Room.show page, however when I go to enter

```
<p><%= message.user.name if message.user %> <small><em><%= "#{time_ago_in_words(message.created_at)} ago" %></em></small></p>
```

I receive a nil can't be converted to a Time value error. Also, I cannot get the Users name to show up. It just registers blank.

Here is the section of my Room.show.html.erb that is registering an error

```
<% @message.each do |message| %>
  <div class="row">
    <p><%= message.user.name if message.user %> <small><em><%= "#{time_ago_in_words(message.created_at)} ago" %></em></small></p>
    <p><%= message.body %></p>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Here is my Message controller

```
    def show
      @rooms = Room.all
      @message = @room.message
    end
```

Here is my Routes file

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do
        devise_for :users
        #resources :messages
        resources :users
        resources :rooms do
          resources :messages
        end

        root 'rooms#index'

    end
```

Message.rb

```
        class Message < ApplicationRecord
           belongs_to :user
           belongs_to :room
        end
```

And room.rb

```
          class Room < ApplicationRecord
             has_many :message
          end
```

Using updated version of rails.

Comment: It should be `has_many :messages`, isn't it?

Comment: unfortunately, that didn't fix the problem. Thank you for noticing this though! I have corrected it in my code but still receive the same Nil error.

Comment: Are you sure about `mesage.created_at` value? Can you proof it isn't `nil`?

Comment: @SheldonBishop Could you please update your current code to the question? I will investigate further.

Comment: I suggest you look up your migration, does it have the `timestamps`. Also, have you tried to get the value in `rails console`, just to be sure that you store the values.

Comment: @Зелёный, I can prove its not nil by going in rails console and looking at Message.all. They all have a created_at value so im assuming that's not the issue.

Comment: @HDox, I haven't changed any of my code. Are there additional files you would like to see? Happy to provide them and thanks for the continued help!

Comment: @JohnBaker, yes my migration file for when I CreateMessages has a t.timestamps value inside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`message.created_at` is `nil`. You can verify it by changing your code slightly:

```
<%= "#{time_ago_in_words(message.created_at || Time.now)} ago" %>
```

This will always show `less than a minute ago` because `message.created_at` is `nil`.

```
<%= "#{time_ago_in_words(message.created_at)} ago" if message.created_at %>
```

This will not show anything because `message.created_at` is `nil`.

I suggest that you use a debugging library like [`pry`](http://pryrepl.org) to help you troubleshoot this. You could do something like this:

```
<% @message.each do |message| %>
  <div class="row">
    <% binding.pry unless message && message.created_at %>
    <p><%= message.user.name if message.user %> <small><em><%= "#{time_ago_in_words(message.created_at)} ago" %></em></small></p>
    <p><%= message.body %></p>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

That will set a breakpoint that will be triggered if `message` or `message.created_at` are `nil`, and allow you to use the Rails console to inspect the variables to help narrow down the problem.

Like others mentioned, you will need to make sure your models are appropriately constructed:

```
class Room < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :messages
end
```

You should also check your `schema.rb` to ensure that the `Message` model has the following:

```
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.index ["room_id"], name: "index_messages_on_room_id"
```

The first is needed because without it `message.created_at` will not exist at all, and the second is needed for the association between the two models.

Your controller code doesn't make any sense and I'm assuming that you manually typed it into your question rather than copying and pasting it. You define `@rooms` as an `ActiveRecord::Relation` collection object, but you call `@room.message`. If you meant `@rooms.message` then that won't work because you're trying to call an instance method on a collection. I'm not sure what you meant here because the code doesn't make sense.

Additionally, you're not implementing a [clean CRUD solution](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#showing-articles). Your `Messages` controller's `show` method should be for rendering a single `Message` object, not for rendering a collection of rooms' messages.

In general there are many problems with the code, the structure, and the example you have typed out. At the very least though, you must make sure that `message.created_at` is not `nil` before attempting to call `time_ago_in_words`, and that all traces back to:

- making sure your models are correctly formed and associated with each other
- making sure your controller is fetching real objects
- making sure your view is appropriately iterating over those real objects

Comment: I added the " || Time.now" and it made everything show up with its correct time! Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: @SheldonBishop I don't think that it is showing the correct time, and that's not the explanation that I gave you. I think you have missed the point of the answers I provided and I don't think you have found the actual solution. I suggest that you carefully re-read what I posted.

Comment: I looked over what you said fully, and I greatly appreciate the in depth explanation. The time so far is correctly showing when the comments were created: 2 days ago, 1 day ago, 24 mins ago, etc... Also yes, the code I posted for my Message Controller is actually my Room Controller code - maybe thats why it didn't make sense. I checked my schema file and all the fields you suggested were present. I have the bye bug gem installed. Would that work ok or do you think I should use pry? I am not familiar with it but am happy to try it if you think its better. Again, thank you for your help

Comment: Im  currently looking through my Room Controller trying to make it more dry, as suggested. However when I switch it from "message = room.messages" to "message = room.message" I receive and undefined method error. I originally had it this way but realized if I used messages vs message it didn't return the error. Am happy to learn the correct way as this will help me more than just a quick fix!